# Unable to communicate with another pod using Service Cluster IP, Using POD IP able to communicate

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress

I have nginx pod and other pod contains gunicorn pod api which I am trying to connect via nginx pod.

When I use POD IP of gunicorn pod in nginx pod, I am able to connect with nginx pod.
Output:

```
root@nginx:/etc/nginx# curl -v http://10.244.1.155:20000/_ems/plant
*   Trying 10.244.1.155:20000...
* Connected to 10.244.1.155 (10.244.1.155) port 20000 (#0)
```

When I used Service, Instead of POD IP, its failing.
Error:

```
root@nginx:/etc/nginx# curl -v http://ems-service.default.svc.cluster.local:20000/_ems/plant;
*   Trying 10.106.43.2:20000...
* connect to 10.106.43.2 port 20000 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to ems-service.default.svc.cluster.local port 20000: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to ems-service.default.svc.cluster.local port 20000: Connection refused
```

Logs:

```
NAME                                                         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS         AGE
pod/ems                                                      1/1     Running            0                5m56s
pod/nginx                                                    1/1     Running            0                4h46m
NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/ems-service        ClusterIP   10.106.43.2    <none>        20000/TCP        103m
[eds@rnd-4 pod-4px]$ kubectl describe service -n default ems-service
Name:              ems-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          name=ems
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.106.43.2
IPs:               10.106.43.2
Port:              <unset>  20000/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         <none>
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Yaml File:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ems
  labels:
    app: ems
spec:
  containers:
    - name: ems
      image: 
      command: ["/bin/sh"]
      args: ["-c", "chmod +x /root/code/run.sh && /root/code/run.sh"]
      env:
      - name: LOGS_DIR
        value: /root/code/logs
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      ports:
      - containerPort: 20000
----------------------------------
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ems-service
spec:
  selector:
    name: ems
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 20000
      targetPort: 80
```

Comment: First, your service endpoint is empty Endpoints:         <none>....when it's good it should have the pod ip instead of none....in your service change your targetPort to 2000 and you should be good to go

Comment: Thanks @Hackerman, Post changing port and defining lables and changing service config with ` app: ems` instead of `name: ems`, it started working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `kubectl describe service` says `Endpoints: <none>` that's usually a clear sign that the Service's `selector:` doesn't match the Pod's `labels:`.  In your setup you have

```yaml
# pod.yaml
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ems
```

```yaml
# service.yaml
spec:
  selector:
    name: ems
```

and these need to match.  The most likely fix is to change `name` to `app` in the Service.

You usually shouldn't run a bare Pod, for a couple of reasons beyond the scope of this question.  I'd recommend changing the Pod to a Deployment, assuming you don't need access to persistent storage.  The Service needs to match the `spec: { template: { metadata: { labels: } } }` per-Pod labels in this case.